# How to make the rest assured Http call more abstract?

Tags: java, rest, rest-assured

Currently this is my code which has the same code , just the POST and PUT are different :

```
private static Response putRequest(String endpoint, T request, int code, String uuid) {
    return Response(buildRequest().body(request).put(endpoint + "/{uuid}", uuid), code);
}
```

AND

```
private static Response postRequest(String endpoint, T request, int code, String uuid){
    return Response(buildRequest().body(request).post(endpoint + "/{uuid}",uuid), code);
}
```

How can I make the calls generic ? The Request parameter will be generic to have more flexibility.

Comment: "*[...] just the POST and PUT are different*" - and the method signatures (`ABC` vs. `XYZ`). Could you specify what you mean by "more abstract"? What is the problem with the current solution? What is your goal?

Comment: quetion is edited for more information

Answer (score 0):

To use a generic type in a static method, you will need to include a generic declaration within the signature of the static method. This is done by inserting `<T>` before the return type.

To make the generic static you want, you would need to change one of the methods to:

```
private static Response postRequest(String endpoint, T request, int code, String uuid) {
    return Response(buildRequest().body(request).post(endpoint + "/{uuid}",uuid), code);
}
```

to

```
private static <T> Response postRequest(String endpoint, T request, int code, String uuid){
    return Response(buildRequest().body(request).post(endpoint + "/{uuid}",uuid), code);
}
```

Comment: what you explained is not my question. I am asking if the calls POST and PUT be made generic as the code is pretty much the same

Answer (score -1):

I am assuming that you want to reuse as much as possible in here. If thats the case you can wrap `post` and `put` operation into a functional interface.

```
public static interface RequestOperation{

    public Request operation(Request r, String s1, String s2);
}

public static <T> Response putRequest(String endpoint, T request, int code, String uuid) {
    return request ( (r, s1, s2) -> r.post(s1, s2), endpoint, request, code, uuid );
}

public static <T> Response postRequest(String endpoint, T request, int code, String uuid){
    return request ( (r, s1, s2) -> r.post(s1, s2), endpoint, request, code, uuid );
}

public static <T> Response request(RequestOperation requestOperation, String endpoint, 
T request, int code, String uuid){        
    return new Response( 
    requestOperation.operation( buildRequest().body(request), endpoint + "/{uuid}",uuid), 
    code );
}

public static class Response{

    public Response(Request r, int code){}
}

public static class Request{

    public <T> Request body(T request){
        return this;
    }

    public Request post(String s, String s1){
        return this;
    }

    public Request put(String s, String s1){
        return this;
    }
}

public static Request buildRequest(){
    return new Request();
}
```